# A finicky Windows 7 Path issue (for setting up java command line)

Tags: java, classpath

I am realy close to solving this, but am having a little trouble setting up my Java command line prompt in windows 7. the funny thing is that I can use java & javac like this:

```
"%javac%"
```

Why is that ? I.e when I try to say `javac *.java` , it won't work; and even `%javac% *.java` won't work (ie it gives me "'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file -" ), but `"%javac%"` works;  .. here is a SS of my "Envir. Variables" -

[image]

Comment: What happens when you type `java -version` ?

Comment: The quotes will interpret your `%javac%` variable. The reason `javac *.java` doesn't work is likely because you don't have `JAVA_HOME` in your `PATH`.

Comment: @admdrew  - Hmm let me try that . thanks!!

Comment: @LittleChild - I get "'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

Comment: @Adel That is cause you dont have the `bin` in your path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment that ***'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file,*** you do not have `jdk bin` folder in your `PATH` environment variable. Add `\path\to\jdk.version\bin` to your `PATH` variable, preceded by a semicolon `;`. You have to add, not overwrite the variable.

Comment: FYI, you probably should have mentioned the error - `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file` - in your original post...

Comment: @FoggyDay Made the edit to incorporate your suggestion. Thank you. =)